# How to get contact (firstname, lastname, contactid, number)

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios9

I have used AddessBook library (for ios8) to get all contact (firstname, lastname, contactId, all phone number). it worked perfect on simulitor.

my code:

```
private func getContacts()->[Person] {

    var peapleOfContact: [Person] = []

    if !self.determineStatus() {
        return peapleOfContact
    }

    if let people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(self.adbk)?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSArray {
        for person in people{
            let contactID = ABRecordGetRecordID(person)
            let firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as! String
            let lastName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as! String
            let personOfContact = Person(id: String(contactID), firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName)
            let numbers:ABMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()
            for ix in 0 ..< ABMultiValueGetCount(numbers) {
                let type = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(numbers,ix).takeRetainedValue() as String
                let number = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers,ix).takeRetainedValue() as! String
                let cleaned = self.removeSpecialCharsFromString(type)
                let shortNumber = self.makeSpecialShortNumberFromString(number)
                let phone = Number(number: number, short: shortNumber, type: cleaned)
                personOfContact.addPhoneNumber(phone)
            }
            peapleOfContact.append(personOfContact)
        }

    }
    return peapleOfContact
}
```

when xcode 7.1.1 is updated and used ios9, this library not work so used ContactUI Framework.

my code:

```
private func getContact(){

    let keysToFetch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle(.FullName),
        CNContactImageDataKey,
        CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]

    let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)

    do {
        try store.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(fetchRequest, usingBlock: { (let contact, let stop) -> Void in
            self.contacts.append(contact)
        })
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

and used like this:

```
self.getContact()
    for contact in self.contacts{
        print("Full name: \(CNContactFormatter.stringFromContact(contact, style: .FullName))")
        print("Give name: \(contact.givenName)")
        print("fimily name: \(contact.familyName)")
        print("Idnetifier name: \(contact.identifier)")

        for phoneNo in contact.phoneNumbers {
            if phoneNo.label == CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile {
                let number = (phoneNo.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
                print("Phone Number: \(number)")
            }
        }
    }
```

but not found contactId. How to get contactId ? How to use ContactUI Framework ?
advise me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 9.*, there is a new framework called 'Contacts'

Usage:

> import Contacts

```
    var validContacts: [CNContact] = []
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()

    // Request for contact access
    contactStore.requestAccessForEntityType(.Contacts) { (granted, e) -> Void in

        if granted {

            do {                    
                // Specify the key fields that you want to be fetched.
                // Note: if you didn't specify your specific field request. your app will crash
                let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactMiddleNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey])

                try contactStore.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(fetchRequest, usingBlock: { (contact, error) -> Void in

                    // Lets filter (optional)
                    if !contact.emailAddresses.isEmpty || !contact.phoneNumbers.isEmpty {
                        validContacts.append(contact)
                    }
                })

                print(validContacts)
            }catch let e as NSError {
                print(e)
            }
        }
    }
```

Parsing:

```
    // Loop through contatcs
        for contact in validContacts {

            var phoneNumbers: [String] = []
            for phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers {
                let value = phoneNumber.value as! CNPhoneNumber
                phoneNumbers.append(value.stringValue)
            }

            var emailAddresses: [String] = []
            for emailAddress in contact.emailAddresses {
                let value = emailAddress.value as! String
                emailAddresses.append(value)
            }

            if let imageData = contact.imageData {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                print("image: \(image)")
            }

            // Lets log
            print("givenName: \(contact.givenName), middleName: \(contact.middleName), familyName: \(contact.familyName), phoneNumbers: \(phoneNumbers), emailAddresses: \(emailAddresses)\n")
        }
```

I have a sample project which implement this.
[GitHub](https://github.com/nferocious76/FetchPhoneContacts)

Comment: thanks answer. I have got contact ID in AddressBook (Int32 type) like this: `let contactID = ABRecordGetRecordID(person)`  Is it impossible to get contact ID ?

Comment: you can just use contact.identifier

Answer (score 0):

This code sample will help you :

```
  public static func refreshContacts(){
        let status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()
        if status == .Denied || status == .Restricted {
            // user previously denied, to tell them to fix that in settings
            return
        }

    // open it

    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    let addressBook: ABAddressBook? = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &error)?.takeRetainedValue()
    if addressBook == nil {
        println(error?.takeRetainedValue())
        return
    }

    // request permission to use it

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook) {
        granted, error in

        if !granted {
            // warn the user that because they just denied permission, this functionality won't work
            // also let them know that they have to fix this in settings
            return
        }

        if let people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSArray {
            for person in people{
                if let name = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as? String {
                    println(name)//persons name
                }
                let numbers:ABMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(
                    person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()
                for ix in 0 ..< ABMultiValueGetCount(numbers) {
                    let label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(numbers,ix).takeRetainedValue() as String
                    let value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers,ix).takeRetainedValue() as! String
                    println("Phonenumber \(label) is \(value))
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code not work. I have checked. Do you use ContactUI Framework ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this working for me. sort according to givenname(firstname). *import Contacts* first

```
let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    var results: [CNContact] = []
    do {
        let request:CNContactFetchRequest
        request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactMiddleNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey])
        request.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.GivenName
        try contactStore.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(request) {
            (contact, cursor) -> Void in
            results.append(contact)
            }
    }
    catch{
        print("Handle the error please")
    }

    print(results)
```